# Er liest das Buch nicht

Tags: word-usage

I can't understand why nicht is positioned in the end of the following sentence:

> Er liest das Buch nicht

According to the following site:
http://german.about.com/od/grammar/a/The-Position-Of-Nicht.htm

> Nicht will usually follow: 
>   **Adverbs that can be organized chronologically**

The problem is - there is no adverb in the presented sentence. 'das Buch' is a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this question, we deal with what information is exactly negated by "nicht".
The information in "Er liest das Buch nicht" is:

- What is (not) done with the book: it is read
- What is (not) read: the book

Compare the following examples:

> Ex.1: "Er liest das Buch `nicht` - er hält es in der Hand."
>   -> He isn't reading the book - he's holding it in his hand.

Here, the "nicht" refers to the act of not reading (the book). Normally, this form is used to just express the verb's inactiveness. So when you say "Der Vogel ist nicht rot", the actual thing that would be happening without the "nicht" is the "being" of the Vogel.

> Ex.2: "Er liest `nicht` das Buch - sondern die Zeitung."
>   -> He isn't reading the book - he's reading a newspaper.

Here, the "nicht" refers to the book (that's not read).

-> Generally, "nicht" appears at the end of a sentence, and whenever it isn't, it refers to other parameters like what the verb applies to or which adjective describes the action. Note the exceptions like compound verbs and others. The site you linked provides very good information.

Comment: So why is "Ich gehe in den Park nicht" wrong, and why does "Ich gehe nicht in den Park" not imply that I am going elsewhere?

Comment: I can't really give you a reason for that, but it seems to me that "in den Park" forces the "nicht" to go before because of it's length. Syntaxes like "Ich schenke dir einen super luxuriösen Wagen nicht" are mostly used for jokes, putting a little delay before the "nicht", so the addressed person thinks he's really getting a car until the very last word negates it. In a serious sentence, "Nicht" would be put before a very long trailing group of words, so we know right away, that the sentence is negated, before hearing the super long string that just describes the car. Hope that makes sence :D

Comment: I did but I don't think it's true. "Ich lese das Buch über einen vegetarischen Vampir, der sich in eine sterbliche verliebt, nicht." Lengths doesn't matter. I really have issues with the common explanations that are out there on the web (including about.com). They just keep copying each other but they always fail at these kind of questions, which are by no means contrived examples. I can give you millions of sentences like that. No offense, I just don't think that really explains what is happening.

Comment: The part "der sich in eine sterbliche verliebt" is an insertion, which doesn't affect the syntax of the main sentence dramatically, as it is treated as one element. My theory is not at all based on resources other than my brain, though...

Comment: Even without that side-sentence it is still longer than the park-part. Trust me. I have done some thinking about this and length is not an issue here.

Comment: @Emanuel Structural linguistically speaking, "in den Park" is a prepositional phrase, which is a separate "branch" of the sentence's structure. In short sentences, typically the pressure is to not separate connected elements across such branches. Meanwhile your vampire example has a marked or "strong" structural interruption that can pretty much get away with anything. That's probably why in the first example it isn't permitted to separate the verb and the negation. (Caveat: my linguistics syntax knowledge *is* rusty, so this lacks precision and technical terms.)

Comment: @Emanuel ... And I see you address a related syntactical analysis in your answer. Upvoted. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie. I have to admit that I didn't fully understand your comment, however, from a semantical point of view it is hard to accept "in den Park" as a separate branch. A problem I often have with linguistics... it is too theoretical. But I can give you a different example that doesn't include a prepositional phrase.. "Ich fahre nicht Bus."

Comment: @Emanuel In a syntactic tree ([e.g.](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/syntax-trees-for-sentences)), it's a branch that is headed by "in" with "den" -> "Park" as two nodes that 'hang' off the "in" head. They form a unit that is independent and removable from the sentence. The "nicht" can't follow it because there is no appropriate node for it to inhabit after the "in" node, except by directly connecting to the sentence as a whole and negating it as a whole, which would be indicated orthographically by ", nicht." instead IIRC.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie... "The unit is independent and removable"... well so is "das Buch" in "Ich lese das Buch nicht." ;). I'd say it is actually more connected as "gehen" alone has a shift in meaning while "lesen" alone doesn't. Also, let's take "rennen" instead. "Ich renne nicht in den Park" not invertible. "Ich renne im Park nicht" (invertible) Why can I put "nicht" final in one case and not in the other. I am dealing with a separate branch in both examples.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie... (ctd.) I didn't study linguistics so I guess if we dig deep enough we might find an explanation that works for all examples I can come up with but I am also quite sure that it'll be rather contrived.

Comment: "Ich renne in den Park nicht" would be like "Ich beschleunige in den Kreisverkehr nicht", which is actually valid, but should be made more obvious by saying like "Ich beschleunige auf der Strecke in den Kreisverkehr hinein nicht". So "in den Park" actually stands for the time when you're running into the park. So "Ich renne in den Park nicht" is somewhat incomplete/unclear, but "Ich renne auf dem Weg in den Park hinein nicht" makes it valid.

Comment: What about the following sentence:
"Ich mag den Loffel nicht"
By reading your answer, 'nicht' should be before the noun - because it's referring to it. Maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: @Sam, it does, but it's a different sentence "Ich renne auf dem Weg nicht". Which is an answer to "wo" whereas "in den Park" is an answer to "wohin". Dative works, accusative doesn't (with regards to final nicht) . That's the big question.

Comment: @InterSys... that is what I mean by default-negation. "Ich mag nicht den Löffel" implies a "but the fork" because it is NOT the default. As a narrowed down rule you could take it as follows. In a construction "verb+ direct object" the default-negation is the verb alone. This can be generalized but not in a comment :)

Comment: Third possibility: "Nicht er liest das Buch – jemand anderes liest es."

Answer (score 2):

The common explanation you can find in books is that we're looking at a Satznegation" (whole sentence negation) as opposed to a "Satzteilnegation" (part of sentence negation).
I don't find that particularly helpful. Nor does it mirror the underlying structures.
So here's my somewhat unorthodox explanation.

The fundamental rule of negation is that "nicht" is right in front of what it negates. In your sentence it seems to be in front of nothing. But that is misleading because the V2-sentence is NOT the usual order of things. In linguistics sentences are transformed to V-final before analyzing the structure because only then does it really show.

> ..., dass ich das Buch nicht lese.

Now we can see, that "nicht" negates the "lesen".

> ..., dass ich nicht das Buch lese.

Here, the "nicht" negates the book.

> ... ,dass nicht ich das Buch lesen.

and here it negates me.
The "nicht" in your example is at the end because the verb was moved forward. However, as soon as we change it to past tense, the "nicht" will not be at the end anymore.

> Ich habe das Buch nicht gelesen.

Comment: This is the third time I am reading you answer but I still can't understand it (I am not saying it's wrong).

Comment: I'd love to help out. Let me know what you're having trouble with and I'll try to rephrase